# What was the story of a serious incident with Galaxy C5 in about 1973

Tags: military, aviation-history, accident-investigation, lockheed-c-5

I am guessing it was a flight in support of the Yom Kippur War in October of 1973 that due a pitot tube failure that Galaxy C5 had to do an emergency landing on Azore with assitance from another plane but finding any details about it spoiled by the higher profile Vietnam War Babylift operation major incident. What caused its pitot tube to fail? The video isn't an accident investigation. It only says their pitot tube failed and they didn't have altitude or speed readings.

Comment: I don't have the opportunity to watch the video right now, but what is it about the incident that the video doesn't explain to your satisfaction? Also, please include some salient points from the video for when (not if) the link goes dead.

Comment: FYI, a part failure is not a mishap.  A part failure may lead to a mishap, but they are distinctly different things.  (like if your car stereo stopped working, that isn't an accident, but if you are fiddling with it while driving and smack into a tree that would be an accident.)

Comment: The airlift to Israel was [Operation Nickel Grass](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Nickel_Grass), which should help your research.